# Simple Past vs. Present Perfect for "Load"

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I wrote:

> After the page **was** loaded, you can apply a filter on the page to automatically extract the main content and eliminate clutters.

It is "After the page has loaded" or "After the page was loaded". I think *was* is correct and *load* is passive. but I saw some sentences including "the page has loaded"

Answer (score 3):

The correct phrasing is,

> After the page **has** loaded, you can apply a filter to automatically extract the main content and eliminate clutter.

"Clutter" should not be "clutters." "On the page" is understood from the context.

Comment: Can you add details why the perfect tense is correct and not the past passive tense?

Comment: You could write, "After the page *was* loaded, *he applied* a filter to automatically extract the main content and eliminate clutter." Or, "*Once the page loads*, a filter *can be applied* to automatically extract the main content and eliminate clutter." However, in general, use of the active voice is preferable to the passive voice.

Comment: I slipped that, the *you can apply*, it shows no coherence with the first clause.

Comment: I think you understand it now just fine!

Comment: +1. You can also say "is loaded" or "has been loaded". Depends on whether we're making the page an agent (reflexive) or a passive object. Both are idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

After the page was loaded, you can....

First off, the verb load can be used transitively or intransitively.

The after clause in the past simple in the sentence presented doesn't sound grammatical. You can say the following instead:

After the page loads, you can...

After the page is loaded, you can.....

After the page has loaded, you can...

After the page has been loaded, you can...

Besides, clutter is an uncountable noun; you should say clutter, not clutters.